# How can we get this dynamically as this folder may not be by the same name always → wp-admin

Tags: plugins, php, plugin-development, wp-admin

```
action="/wp-admin/admin.ajax.php?action=slb_save_subscription"
```

The above is a part of the `code in WordPress`, but I have read somewhere in the past that these folders can be changed.

How can we `dynamically` get this part through some PHP function or code?

Comment: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/admin_url/

Comment: WP Admin rarely changes, but, why bother with the old `admin-ajax.php` when you can use a REST API endpoint for your AJAX and call `rest_url`? E.g. the posts endpoint is at `rest_url( "wp/v2/posts/" )`, it looks prettier, it even gives you human readable error messages if you make a mistake

Comment: I was doing a course at udemy seems outdated. I will explore the rest API. Thank you so much for the guidance.